# AS3: Cant get the length of dynamically created MC, outside of its function

Tags: actionscript-3, function

I want to get the size of parent_mc after it has had all the content of a dynamic folder loaded,
I tried :

```
function initmyWidth():Number
            {
                var myWidth:Number = galleryArr.length * 400;
                return myWidth;
            }
```

it gives me the correct number if its nested in function onGalleryLoaded but outside of the fun ton it traces 0. there a way to pass galleryArr.length  outside the onGalleryLoaded function?

```
 var galleryArr:Array = [];

var parent_mc:Sprite = new Sprite();

addChild(parent_mc);
parent_mc.y = 112;
parent_mc.x = 300;

function onGalleryLoaded(e:Event):void
{

    var imageX:int = 0;
    var imageY:int = 0;


    for each (var image:Sprite in galleryArr)
    {

        var my_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

        my_mc.addChild(image);



        parent_mc.addChild(my_mc);

        my_mc.width = 400;
        my_mc.height = 400;
        my_mc.x -= parent_mc.width;
        my_mc.y = imageY;


        imageX -=  my_mc.width + PADDING_X;
        if ( (imageX+my_mc.width) > stage.stageWidth )
        {
            imageX = parent_mc.width;
            imageY = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you populating `galleryArr`?

Comment: From an XML loader @Marcela

Comment: `parent_mc` should be added to stage for `width` to return correct value. It's likely your MC does not have access to stage, thus width is bogus.

Comment: @Vesper, I don't believe that's correct. `DisplayObject`s have a width and height regardless of whether or not they're on the stage. The issue at hand here is that `galleryArr` is not populated at the time that `initmyWidth` is being called.

Comment: @Marcela I have experience with dynamically populated MCs (`Sprite` instances) that consisted of numerous moving shapes, and while that sprite wasn't on the stage, the width is traced -10 million (!), but as soon as I add that sprite to stage, trace width and instantly remove, the width is gathered correctly.

Comment: @Vesper, that's actually very interesting. I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot expect to get an accurate width until you know how many elements are in `gallyerArr`. This isn't a case of passing a value from outside of a function, but rather a case of attempting to do something synchronously while an asynchronous process hasn't completed (in this case, your load event).

Once `onGalleryLoaded` has been called, `initmyWidth` will function as expected.